# PHP find cheapest permutation

Tags: php, mathematics

I have multiple products that all have sizes and I need to find the cheapest configuration that meets the minimum required size.

For example, John needs a minimum of 10 litres of storage - it can be more, but not less.

There are 2L, 3L, 5L, 8L and 10L options (but this can change).

As an example, it might be cheaper to get:

- 1x10L container OR
- 2x5L containers OR
- 1x2L, 1x3L and 1x5L OR
- 4x3L (this one is over 10 L, but it is still possible that it will be cheaper)

So far I've tried looping over and over up to 4 times (because typically the maximum requirement will be 40 L), but in some cases I am running out of memory, and it doesn't seem like the most efficient way of doing it.

````
// Size is in mL

$available_containers = [
[
  'id' => 22700,
  'price' => 1190,
  'size' => 2000,
],
[
  'id' => 22701,
  'price' => 1245,
  'size' => 3000,
],
[
  'id' => 22702,
  'price' => 1415,
  'size' => 4000,
],
[
  'id' => 22715,
  'price' => 12300,
  'size' => 5000,
],
[
  'id' => 22706,
  'price' => 1740,
  'size' => 5000,
],
[
  'id' => 22703,
  'price' => 1510,
  'size' => 5000,
],
[
  'id' => 22707,
  'price' => 1790,
  'size' => 6000,
],
[
  'id' => 22704,
  'price' => 1770,
  'size' => 6000,
],
[
  'id' => 22708,
  'price' => 2215,
  'size' => 7000,
],
[
  'id' => 22705,
  'price' => 2195,
  'size' => 8200,
],
[
  'id' => 22709,
  'price' => 2660,
  'size' => 8200,
],
[
  'id' => 22710,
  'price' => 2799,
  'size' => 10000,
],
[
  'id' => 22711,
  'price' => 2910,
  'size' => 12500,
],
[
  'id' => 22712,
  'price' => 3260,
  'size' => 15000,
],
[
  'id' => 22713,
  'price' => 4130,
  'size' => 20000,
],
[
  'id' => 22714,
  'price' => 3770,
  'size' => 27000,
]
];

$required_size = 8; // Can change.
$container_install = 5;

foreach ( $available_containers as $v ){
  foreach ( $available_containers as $v2 ){
    foreach ($available_containers as $v3 ) {
      foreach ( $available_containers as $v4 ){

        $all_configs = [
          [
            'size' => $v['size'],
            'configuration' => [ $v['size'] ],
            'price' => $v['price'],
          ],
          [
            'size' => $v['size'] + $v2['size'],
            'configuration' => [ $v['size'], $v2['size'] ],
            'price' => $v['price'] + $v2['price'] + $container_install,
          ],
          [
            'size' => $v['size'] + $v2['size'] + $v3['size'],
            'configuration' => [ $v['size'], $v2['size'], $v3['size'] ],
            'price' => $v['price'] + $v2['price'] + $v3['price'] + $container_install + $container_install,
          ],
          [
            'size' => $v['size'] + $v2['size'] + $v3['size'] + $v4['size'],
            'configuration' => [ $v['size'], $v2['size'], $v3['size'], $v4['size'] ],
            'price' => $v['price'] + $v2['price'] + $v3['price'] + $v4['price'] + $container_install + $container_install + $container_install,
          ],
        ];


        foreach ( $all_configs as $c ){
          if ( $c['size'] >= $required_size ){
            $configuration[] = array(
              'configuration' => $c['configuration'],
              'size' => $c['size'],
              'price' => $c['price'],
            );
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


// Sort by price.
$sorted_configs = array_sort($configuration, 'price', SORT_ASC); // This function simply sorts all permutations by price
```
````

Comment: That's an expensive 5L container (#22715).  Sure you haven't added an extra `0`?

Comment: Haha thanks @AJNeufeld. Yes. Containers are actually not what I'm calculating, but I've used it to simplify the idea.

Comment: I'd call it the cheapest combination rather than permutation, because the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is an instance of [Integer Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming). ILP is NP-hard, so an algorithm to find the optimal solution will not be much faster than brute-force. However, a common technique to find an approximate optimum is to solve it as a [Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem without the integer restrictions, then round the results up or down as necessary. Fortunately, many [libraries](http://www.phpsimplex.com/en/) exist to solve non-integer LP quite efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> foreach ( $available_containers as $v ){
>   foreach ( $available_containers as $v2 ){
>     foreach ($available_containers as $v3 ) {
>       foreach ( $available_containers as $v4 ){
> ```

When you have this many loops, it's time to think about replacing the nesting with recursion.

---

> ```
>         $all_configs = [
>           [
>             'size' => $v['size'],
>             'configuration' => [ $v['size'] ],
>             'price' => $v['price'],
>           ],
> ```

Yes, this is very inefficient.

- It considers each one-container solution \$N^3\$ times, where \$N\$ is the number of containers.
- If the one container already meets the size requirement then it's inefficient to consider larger sets which include it.
- If you've already considered `[#22707, #22704, #22708, #22705]` then there's no point considering `[#22704, #22707, #22708, #22705]`. The simple solution is to work with indices and iterate starting at the index of the previous selection.

Again, a recursive approach would be preferable: it would kill three or four birds with one stone.

---

> ```
>         foreach ( $all_configs as $c ){
>           if ( $c['size'] >= $required_size ){
>             $configuration[] = array(
>               'configuration' => $c['configuration'],
>               'size' => $c['size'],
>               'price' => $c['price'],
>             );
> ...
>
> // Sort by price.
> $sorted_configs = array_sort($configuration, 'price', SORT_ASC); // This function simply sorts all permutations by price
> ```

I don't think you need both of those comments - in fact, neither says anything which isn't obvious from the code.

However, you also don't need to build an array of solutions or to sort, at least given the specification:

> I need to find **the** cheapest configuration that meets the minimum required size

(my emphasis). Just track the best found so far.

Comment: Thanks Peter. There are some cases where it would be cheaper to get TWO containers over one, though. Also, there are cases where a larger container might be on special, so it might be cheaper to get a 10L over an 8L, for example. I'm not sure if you've considered this? I think I have an alternate solution now anyway.

Comment: @Mando, it might be cheaper to get containers X and Y than container Z, but I'm assuming that it will never be cheaper to get containers X and Z than just Z. If some containers have negative prices, the cheapest configuration is to buy an infinite number of those containers...

Comment: Yes - That is correct.